# Is it possible to access the queries in a file created by SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to access the queries and procedures in a file created by SQL Server without installing SQL Server? Problem is that I am having problems to install the SQL server / Express version.

Comment: What type of file is it? (Extension would help)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When all else fails - always try to open files in notepad and see what happens.

In this case, .sql files definitely can be opened with notepad - they are just text files. The extension is just there to give you the ability to double-click on them and by default open in Management Studio (or whatever you want to use to edit SQL files).

Comment: thanks for this simple but useful tip!! in fact among the garbage text I am able to read the queries :-)